# How to start an automated jenkins job with variable parameters without using CLI

Tags: http, post, jenkins, http-post

Scenario:

1. Jenkins is running on a server to which I do not have access to. I cannot use jenkins CLI in this case.
2. I do have access to the jenkins web interface via a url and I can see the job progress and everything.
3. There is a build job configured to be run by jenkins. It can be run on an on demand basis using the web interface.

Requirement:

Currently I can specify the parameters defining this external event in the jenkins job web interface and start the job. But it is manual ( I have to do this).

**I want to run the job above based on an external event in an automated fashion, which means:**

1. When external event happens start the build specifying the parameters of this external event, wait for build to complete, then if another event happens, repeat.

**Question:**

Without using jenkins CLI, can I pass the parameters defining the external event to jenkins url as url POST parameters ?

Conclusion:

This way I can monitor the external event and if it happens send its parameters to jenkins url and start a build.

Answer (score 7):

You can start a job by sending a POST to the `buildWithParameters` endpoint. You can also just string together a query string and GET to that endpoint.

A couple tips:

- If your Jenkins instance is secured then you'll want to configure a build trigger token.
- If your Jenkins has CSRF protection enabled, any POST needs to include a valid crumb.

See: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build and https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API

Comment: Can you please give me an example of a url I could use to start a build with parameters ? Also how would I state the value list in the url if the parameter can take a list of values?

Comment: Say you have a job at http://zombo.com/jenkins/job/foobar. You can invoke a build with parameters at http://zombo.com/jenkins/job/foobar/buildWithParameters?delay=0s&param1=value&param2=value

Comment: "You can also just string together a query string and GET to that endpoint." - This does not work for me. Jenkins says "You must use POST method to trigger builds."